# What "Document interfaces with descriptions" means in a Cisco CCNA PT Activity?

Tags: networking

I just started to study for Cisco CCNA certification and in my 1st PT Activity i cant get what this task means. Can someone help me? What i have to do?

The complete task is this:

```
Document interfaces with descriptions on the College router interfaces and the Faculty switch virtual interface.
```

Comment: I hate to say this but... If you have trouble reading the question and understanding it, you're in for a world of hurt. You're expected to "Document" that is to say "write documentation" about what the interfaces are, and describe them in some consistant manner. Documentation is life for a sysadmin. You will hate it, you will love it. It will break your heart, and it'll save your life. Documentation is what seperates the amateur from the professional.

Comment: I filled my addressing table on an excel already. So i don't have to do something in Packet Tracer? Is there any command where i can describe (comment) each interface in cisco IOS?

Comment: Damn it! I submitted it and i missed those documentations and scored 88%. I still don't get what i had to do :S

Comment: Ahh, *that* might be on topic. You might want to edit your question to reflect this - as I read it, it sounded like you had trouble parsing what 'document' meant, which had be baffled.

Comment: Yeah i missed to do the following: Network:Switch 1:Ports:Vlan1:Description, Network:Router:Ports:GigabitEthernet0/0:Description, Network:Router:Ports:GigabitEthernet0/1:Description

Comment: I had to do something `like interface ethernet 0`
    `description physics department AppleTalk LAN` Thanks anyway @JourneymanGeek. I have to wait to answer my question because i am new!

Comment: [Palmface](http://media.moddb.com/cache/images/mods/1/14/13118/thumb_620x2000/DoubleFacepalm.jpg) is the only thing left? Maybe you can ask them for a copy ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just found [this](http://www.cisco.com/en/US/docs/ios/12_2/interface/configuration/guide/icflogin.html)!

For example...

```
interface ethernet 0
description physics department AppleTalk LAN
```